# How do I deploy a Cloud ML Training job with additional python dependencies?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I use additional python dependencies in my tensorflow program. How do I deploy the training job through Cloud ML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dependencies are on PyPI, you can declare them as dependencies in a custom setup.py file. See http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html . Once you have authored your setup.py file, use `gcloud beta ml jobs submit training` as normal and your code will be built using your setup.py file.

Run `gcloud beta ml jobs submit training --help` for more information.

If your dependency is not on PyPI, you can follow the instructions here, http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html#packages-not-on-pypi, or you can manually pass your tar.gz archives to gcloud with, the `--packages` flag.